# Django DateTimeField adding timedelta

Tags: django, datetime, timezone, django-admin, timedelta

something strange is happening in my django application:
I have a model which includes a DateTimeField:

```
class Event(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return pretty_print_datetime(self.start_time))
def pretty_print_datetime(date):
    return date.strftime('%A, %x, %H Uhr').replace(' 0', ' ')
```

Furthermore I added some functionality that allows me to create multiple events at once. They all have a different day but the start time should be the same:

```
class EventAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = EventForm
    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        obj.save()
        if not change:
            # Create more events
            repetitions = form.cleaned_data['number_of_repetitions']
            interval = form.cleaned_data['interval_of_repetitions']
            for i in range(repetitions):
                new_event = Event.objects.get(pk=obj.pk)
                new_event.pk = None
                new_event.start_time += timedelta(days=(i+1)*interval)
                new_event.save()
```

Now the strange part: Whenever I create an event (starting at 17:00) it will store the event (and all the other events that I automatically create) in the database with a starting time of "...15:00+00". I wouldn't worry about it since the admin interface still tells me that my event starts at 17:00 but unfortunately it tells me that my original events starts at 17:00 while all other events start at 16:00. How can this be? Even if the database stores the format differently, how can the other events start at a different time?

Should I start to care more about time zone awareness, if so: What should I do?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: How do you create the 'repetitions' ?

Comment: That's not a timedelta, that's a timezone.